# AS3 UILoader Registration point, all photos not in center

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

**I have some prlblems to center my photos in stage, I use Flash cs5 as3 UILoader, and the photos size is all are defferents, so I tried to move the UILoader Registration point to the center on the top with free transform tool, but Is not change anything at all.
I don't want to check the ScaleContent in the Properties, made those photos very bad qualities.
1000px  x 700px highth stage, and photos should be 400px high.
What should I do?*

```
      import flash.utils.Timer;
      import flash.events.TimerEvent;
      import flash.events.MouseEvent;
      import flash.events.Event;
      import fl.containers.UILoader;
      import flash.text.TextField;
      import flash.display.SimpleButton;
      import fl.transitions.Tween;
      import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
      import fl.transitions.easing.*;
      stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
      var myImage:String = "smallWildlife/00.jpg";
      var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myImage);
      uiLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
      uiLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
      uiLoader.load(request);

      function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
      {

status_txt.text = "Percentage Loaded:" + Math.round(event.target.percentLoaded);
       }

       function completeHandler(event:Event):void
       {   
       uiLoader.x = stage.stageWidth/6 - uiLoader.content.width/6;
       uiLoader.y = stage.stageHeight/100 - uiLoader.content.height/700;
       new Tween(uiLoader,"rotationX",Elastic.easeOut,90,0,4,true);
       }

        next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);

       //variable is a container that holds some value...;
       var imageNumber:Number = 0;

      function checkNumber():void
      {
next_btn.visible = true;
back_btn.visible = true;
//If the imageNumber is = 58, then do something...
if (imageNumber == 58)
{
    trace(imageNumber);
    next_btn.visible = false;
}
//if the imageNumber is = 1, then don't show the back button
if (imageNumber == 0)
 {
    trace(imageNumber);
        back_btn.visible = false;
  }
        }
       checkNumber();

       function nextImage(evtObj:MouseEvent):void
       {
//Adding to the current value +1
imageNumber++;
uiLoader.source = "smallWildlife/0" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
checkNumber();
      }

       back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backImage);

      function backImage(evtObj:MouseEvent):void
      {
//Subtract 1 from the current value
imageNumber--;
uiLoader.source = "smallWildlife/0" + imageNumber + ".jpg";
checkNumber();
      }

      stop();
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{   
    uiLoader.x = stage.stageWidth/6 - uiLoader.content.width/6;
    uiLoader.y = stage.stageHeight/100 - uiLoader.content.height/700;
    new Tween(uiLoader,"rotationX",Elastic.easeOut,90,0,4,true);
}
```

to this

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{   
    var spr = new Sprite();

    // Place spr anywhere on the stage
    spr.x = stage.stageWidth / 6 - uiLoader.content.width / 6;
    spr.y = stage.stageHeight / 100 - uiLoader.content.height / 700;
    spr.addChild( uiLoader );

    addChild( spr );

    // Center uiLoader in spr
    uiLoader.x = - uiLoader.width / 2;
    uiLoader.y = - uiLoader.height / 2;

    new Tween( spr, "rotationX", Elastic.easeOut, 90, 0, 4, true );
}
```

Comment: go to bradmarkel.net and cleck the willife gallery, I just can not make it right.

Comment: I now see your problem - your **uiLoader** is not a **UILoader object** but a **Graphic** inside a **Sprite** inside a **MovieClip**. What you need to do is **click** the **windows tab**, then click **components**, find the **UILoader**, then drag it to the stage and name it **uiLoader**. That should do. Here it is doing xRotation: 'http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1360365998'. Good luck with your website!

Comment: I don't get this code of yours: this.uiLoader.x = (-this.uiLoader.width) / 402; this.uiLoader.y = (-this.uiLoader.height) / 235; Try going back to this: uiLoader.x = - uiLoader.width / 2; uiLoader.y = - uiLoader.height / 2;

Comment: you can see the website, bradmarkel.net, wildlife, all photos are not on the center.

Comment: Did you know how to make all those photos in the center in the website?

Comment: Send me the fla. files so we can get this over with. Here's my email add: khailcs@yahoo.com

Comment: @khaics, Thanks, I will sent the Fla files, but I want to make sure is only Fla files? or all the file with photos?

Comment: Thanks, I will sent the Fla files, but I want to make sure is only Fla files? or all the file with photos?

Comment: ,I did send with photos along to your email!

Comment: Didn't receive your email.

Comment: ,I fixed the problem, sorry I get back this late. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The registration point is the little crosshair that comes up when you're editing MovieClips, not the anchor point of the transformation tool.

Comment: Hi David, UILoader, how to change the UILoader registration point?

Comment: @LilyMm It's not easy doing it dynamically, but if you're using the IDE, then just edit the UILoader MovieClip and move it around.

Comment: Hi David, I use AS3 Flash CS5, I don't know IDE, so I change UILoader to a MovieClip?

Comment: @LilyMm CS5 is an IDE. What exactly is your UILoader if it's not a MovieClip?

Comment: @Aavid, I just drag the UILoader component to the stage, that's how I use.

Comment: David, sorry spell your name wrong. I did convert UILoader component to a symbol, but I have error. 1006

Comment: @LilyMm Can you post the line that it refers to? And for future reference, you don't have to use @ David since comments on my questions automatically come up in my notifications.

Comment: -David, I don't know much about his website, I hope I do right. Line, mean ----? bradmarkel.net, I made this website, but have problems with center those phontos.

Comment: @LilyMm I was referring to the part of the code that the error points to.

Comment: -David, I am chinese, some times it's hard for me to understand. what should I do to make my photos in center of stage??? try this www.bradmarkel.net

Comment: @LilyMm You can always email me the .fla and I can show you how it's done. Or follow this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94V1R68H5FQ&edufilter=Db24N54Eu_vpe4P65Iz5FA

Comment: -David, this video is not working, and I need change uiLoader registration.

Comment: -David, in youtube that video I can watch, but the video is for teach change the movie clip registration point, but UILoader is not the same way to change registration point, right?

Comment: @LilyMm What exactly is UILoader? A Graphic?

Comment: -David, uiLoader component, dynamic loader to load photos in Flash, so it's not a Graphic.